# PHP Form Validation - Simple

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am struggling hugely with PHP, and would like to add some very simple validation on my email field so that the users' email addresses must contain '@' in them.

Please could someone help me. I am aware of there being numerous other threads similar to this, however, I cannot seem to rectify my code by using others' threads.

I would really appreciate help with this, but I do ask that if you're kind enough to help, please try not to restructure too much of my code as I would like to do this as simply as possible with my existing code in place.

HTML code:

```
<form action="Scripts/studentinfo.php" method="get" id="studentinfo" onsubmit="return checkform()">

<fieldset>
    <legend> Get in Contact </legend>
    <label>
    Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" value="your email address" />
    </label>
    <label>
    What department would you like to contact?
    <select name="subject">
       <option value="Complaint">Complaint</option>
       <option value="Website Issue">Website Issue</option>
       <option value="General Enquiry">General Enquiry</option>
    </select>
    </label>
<br/>
    <label>
    First Name: <input type="text" name="Firstname" value="first name" />
    </label>
    <label>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="Lastname" value="last name" />
    </label>
    <label>
    Gender
<br/>
        Male: 
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked="checked" />
        Female:
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" />
        </label>
        <label>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="15" name="comment" value="please tell us what you think"> </textarea>
        </label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

PHP code:

```
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Main Stylesheet" href="/stylesheet.css" />
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Alternative Stylesheet" href="/alternate%20stylesheet.css" />
</head>

<?php
// pull out the values from the request stream sent by the form
// and store those values into memory variables

$email   = $_REQUEST['email'];
$webmail   = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$firstName    = $_REQUEST['Firstname'];
$lastName  = $_REQUEST['Lastname'];
$sex     = $_REQUEST['sex'];
$to = 'email address';
$comment   =$_REQUEST['comment'];
$subject   =$_REQUEST['subject'];


$header    = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"';
$header   .= ' "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">';
$htmlhead  = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">';
$htmlhead .= '<head><title>Feedback Recieved</title>';
$htmlhead .= '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>';
$htmlbody  = '<body>';

// use the variables that store the information sent from the form.
 mail($to, $subject,"You have received the following feedback:". $comment, "from " . $firstName . " " . $lastName, "From: $email");
$htmlbody .= "<center><h1>Thank You</h1>";
$htmlbody .= "<p><b>" . $firstName . " " .  $lastName ;
$htmlbody .= "</b>, we've recieved an email from your email address: <b>" . $email . "</b>, and will respond as soon as possible!</p></center>";
$htmlbody .= "</body></html>";

// use echo to write all the information out back to the browser
echo $header . $htmlhead . $htmlbody ;
echo '<center>To return, click <a href="/is0502/index.html">here</a>.</center>';
?>
```

Comment: Use javascript to qualify user input before submission.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're posting to a different PHP file than the one you had the form on, you have two choices:

1. Redirect back to the form page to present the error
2. Display an error and halt execution of the page

The first option is the better option (as a fallback to on-page javascript or HTML5 validation).  To do this, you must check the value of `$_POST['email']`

```
<?php
// pull out the values from the request stream sent by the form
// and store those values into memory variables

$email   = $_REQUEST['email'];
if (strpos($email,'@') == 0) {
   header("Location: http://[URL OF SOURCE PAGE]?error=bademail"); // replace with correct URL
   exit;
}
```

Now, there are lots of ways to pass back the error message to the originating page, but the simplest example just adds a GET parameter to the URL.

Just checking for an @ sign is a bit simplistic for email validation.  You need at least one character before the @ sign and at least one character before the '.' and at least two letters after the last '.' for the TLD (e.g. .com, .co, .video).  This would be easier to check via regular expressions using preg_match instead of strpos.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at this page [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) for various filters and informations about them , about what they do. But let me post for you the simple and accurate filter for email that is present in php.

```
<?php
// pull out the values from the request stream sent by the form
// and store those values into memory variables

$email   = $_REQUEST['email'];
$webmail   = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$firstName    = $_REQUEST['Firstname'];
$lastName  = $_REQUEST['Lastname'];
$sex     = $_REQUEST['sex'];
$to = 'email address';
$comment   =$_REQUEST['comment'];
$subject   =$_REQUEST['subject'];

// New code added for email validation
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
  echo("Email is not valid");
  exit();
}

$header    = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"';
$header   .= ' "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">';
$htmlhead  = '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">';
$htmlhead .= '<head><title>Feedback Recieved</title>';
$htmlhead .= '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>';
$htmlbody  = '<body>';

// use the variables that store the information sent from the form.
 mail($to, $subject,"You have received the following feedback:". $comment, "from " . $firstName . " " . $lastName, "From: $email");
$htmlbody .= "<center><h1>Thank You</h1>";
$htmlbody .= "<p><b>" . $firstName . " " .  $lastName ;
$htmlbody .= "</b>, we've recieved an email from your email address: <b>" . $email . "</b>, and will respond as soon as possible!</p></center>";
$htmlbody .= "</body></html>";

// use echo to write all the information out back to the browser
echo $header . $htmlhead . $htmlbody ;
echo '<center>To return, click <a href="/is0502/index.html">here</a>.</center>';
?>
```

You can also use the javascript jquery form validation plugin to validate the forms before submission but that can be overriden by users as it's client side.

[jQuery form validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/)

Comment: Thank you so much for that, I really appreciate it. Is there a way that it would show the error message without continuing to submit the form and subsequently losing the inputs?

Comment: @Billy if your form is on the same file where your php code is located then you can use the submited inputs and just re-echo them into value="" , else you can use sessions , and save the form data into session and when the use is back to the page of form then get the input data from session and after that clear those inputs from session.

Comment: I really do apologise, I'm an extreme coding noob. How would that look like?

Comment: @Billy please edit the answer and post the code with form html markup included. i will look at it and edit for you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? :/

Comment: @Billy edit your question and add the form code in it.